# Extract string inside double-quotes - why the sed command doesn't work and the grep -o works?

Tags: sed, grep

I have a big log file with multiple strings, and I'm trying to get the ClOrdID field like:

```
ClOrdID="123456"
ClOrdID="123654"
(...)
```

In the middle of this file I have strings with the following message:

```
$$ grep -i "Message processing FAILED" mylog | head -1
2020-10-02 09:30:00,622 ERROR [LAWT1] etc... etc... - Message processing FAILED: <NewOrderSingle etc.. MsgType="D" ClOrdID="123456" Rule80A="A" etc.../></NewOrderSingle>
```

I realized that if I use "grep -o", I can get exactly what I want:

```
$$ grep -i "Message processing FAILED" mylog | grep -o '\sClOrdID=\".[^.\"]*\"' | sed 's/ //g' | head -1
ClOrdID="123456"
```

But if I try to use sed, it just doesn't work. It prints the ClOrdID + everything else after it (besides the ending part ...NewOrderSingle>):

```
$$ grep -i "Message processing FAILED" mylog | sed -rn 's/.* (ClOrdID=".*)" .*/\1/p' | head -1
ClOrdID="123456" Rule80A="A" etc...
```

Can someone help me to find out what's wrong with the sed command? I'm trying to get more familiarized with sed.

Comment: Try `sed -rn 's/.* (ClOrdID="[^"]*") .*/\1/p'`

Comment: Oh, that works! Why is that? Put as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use this `sed` that uses a negated character class `[^"]*` instead of greedy `.*`. `[^"]` matches any character that is not a `"` but `.` matches any character and `".*"` will match until the very last `"` in input.

```
sed -rn 's/.* (ClOrdID="[^"]*") .*/\1/p'
```

Also you must keep closing `:` inside the capturing group.

Comment: I didn't realize that sed uses the same logic of grep -o, it makes sense, thank you.

Comment: It should be noted that if there were two or more occurrences of `ClOrdID` on a line, only the last would be captured (again owing to greedy matches).